# Robolectric Installation

Tags: android, robolectric

I'm trying to get Robolectric up and running by following [thecodepath](https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/Robolectric-Installation-for-Unit-Testing) tutorial on github. However, when running the test, eclipse tries to download `org/robolectric/android-all/4.3_r2-robolectric-0/android-all-4.3_r2-robolectric-0.jar`. What exactly is this 30+ mb .jar file for? Is it supposed to replace the `android.jar` file from the tutorial?

Comment: Have you resolved this? If so, please choose an answer.

Answer (score 8):

Let me first ask а question: **Why do we need Robolectric for unit testing Android?**

And the answer is that `android.jar` is shipped with contracts of classes and utilities methods only. That means every method, every function and constructor in this jar just have one line of code:

```
throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
```

You can only compile your code against this jar and never run on a desktop JVM. If you try to run then you will get an exception thrown as soon as you try to instantiate an android class or call any android utility method.

`Robolectric` tries to solve this problem. From the beginning it customises `ClassLoader` and every call to the android code is replaced with a `Robolectric` implementation. That gave us possibility to test our code on desktop JVM. But that is quite hard to re-implement whole android as well you trap in situation when you test against something different that is present on devices.

So the strategy was changed from `Robolectric` version 2. It tries to use as much as possible android source code which is open sourced from the beginning. That is why the first run of your tests `Robolectric` downloads and caches own android.jar which is compiled from android sources. It is done to make sure that our tests environment behaviour is close to behaviour that we have on the devices.

I would recommend you to read more about `Robolectric` on their [blog](http://robolectric.blogspot.nl), [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/robolectric). As well you can find plenty of presentations on slideshare and youtube about it. And I encourage you to contribute to `Robolectric` project on [github](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric) as soon as you are confident with it and want to give back your gratitude to the community.

Comment: I must admit that adding a download process as part of the first run is a problematic choice. They should enable users to be offline when running this for the first time. I am sitting in a place with poor Internet connection and need to wait an hour for this JAR file to download. I already have android.jar locally and in the past that was enough. I understand the limitation, so I guess I should probably just download the file in advance to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I was trying to set up Robolectric for the first time. The reason for my problem was, my project src files were in the package:

```
com.example
```

But my test files were not inside a package. When I moved my test files to:

```
com.example
```

The problem got resolved. I hope this might help.

Comment: This still does not solve my problem! Its still trying to download the jars and failing. Anything else I'm missing?

Comment: Same here. Moving the test files didn't solve the problem. Any suggestions?